# Integrate Only DM (Document Management) from Alfresco

Tags: integration, alfresco, dm

Integrate Only DM (Document Management) from Alfresco

I have a question, we are doing POC (Proof of Concept) for Alfresco integration with our application and we will be using Alfresco only for Document Management purpose and nothing else.

And we will be developing our own UI for Alfresco DM, so we will connect/integrate with Alfresco Foundation API.

So can anyone tell me if this is possible directly to take DM only from Alfresco for Embedded Alfresco Deployment/Integration, or (a harder way) remove/comment out all other-than DM related Spring beans and their references from config xml files.

Why we want to do this is ---> non-DM related implementation in Alfresco and their dependency jars are making our application's EAR size beyond 200MB and that not only will affect maven compiling and building of total code and development of future code and publishing time of EAR in JBoss is in 15 -20 mins range.

In case anyone has previously tried this, please suggest.

Comment: Could you not just run Alfresco as its own WebApp, and integrate with it using CMIS for your DM requirements?

Answer (score 0):

I tried a couple of years ago to bootstrap the [`FirstFoundationClient`](http://svn.alfresco.com/repos/alfresco-open-mirror/alfresco/HEAD/root/projects/sdk/samples/FirstFoundationClient/) as a Maven project. While it's indeed possible to pull it off and only selects the artifacts you need (although don't expect to cut the whole size to 1/10th), it's not as immediate as its `ant` counterpart.

I'd suggest you to look at the Maven support for Alfresco [project](http://code.google.com/p/maven-alfresco-archetypes/) and derive the POM structure for your project.

I'd start with the `FirstFoundationClient` to bootstrap your build configuration as it really only depends on core services.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I am currently going through spring bean context xmls, will comment out unnecessary beans, but carefully.